# How to write preference values with androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1 in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I know that preference operation has upgraded to androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1

I can Code A to read the preference values "signature".

How can I write a new value to the preference values "signature" with androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1 in kotlin?

**Code A**

```
val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity_context)
val name = sharedPreferences.getString("signature", "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like the old preference library:

```
val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity_context)
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("signature", value).apply()
```

Just make sure that you import from:

```
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager;
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that all is same except `import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager;`?

Comment: In my mind, `androidx.preference:preference` have improved the read and write preference value, but they are the same based your opinion.

Comment: I think that `androidx.preference.PreferenceManager` is being evolved [androidx releases](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference) compared to the previous PreferenceManager (which is being deprecated). If you compare theese two classes the base is the same.